# Magento 2. Admin Password customization

Tags: magento2, admin, password

Each password follows different rules to be considered valid.

- What rules are required for Magento 2 Admin Password?
- Where can this rules be found (GUI or Code)
- Does Magento2 offer out of the box functionality to apply custom rules to admin password (e.g a given regex or password length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***What rules are required for Magento 2 Admin Password?***

Answer: Minimum 7 Character and include both Number and Alphabetic character. Can not reuse an old password.

***Where can this rules be found (GUI or Code)?***

Answer: Code. File/Code Path: /vendor/magento/module-user/Model/UserValidationRules.php

***Does Magento2 offer out of the box functionality to apply custom rules to admin password (e.g a given regex or password length)?***

Answer: No

There are some rules come out of the box which can be found in configuration:

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security
```